# Convert UTC Date to local Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am converting from epoch time (which is in UTC) to a format as shown below. Now I tried different SO answers to convert `UTCDate` from `UTC` to local time. But I am not getting the local time.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
String epochTime = "1436831775043";

Date UTCDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(epochTime));
Date localDate; // How to get this?

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
String result = simpleDateFormat.format(UTCDate);
```

Also, the conversion has to be done without the help of any external library.

Comment: Have you tried [`SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale))?

Comment: Or maybe [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer But it says, "This constructor may not support all locales."

Comment: @KevinRichards Yes, but have you tried?  What about `SimpleDateFormat#setTimeZone`?

Comment: Any chance you can stop using the deprecated Date and switch to OffsetDateTime and LocalDateTime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your time zone in the formatter:

```
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Comment: Oops, it did works! The timezone of my emulator was different.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8

```
String epochTime = "1436831775043";

Instant utcInstant = new Date(Long.parseLong(epochTime)).toInstant();
ZonedDateTime there = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(utcInstant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));

System.out.println(utcInstant);
LocalDateTime here = there.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(here);
```

Which outputs:

```
2015-07-13T23:56:15.043Z
2015-07-14T09:56:15.043
```

## After thoughts...

I think you're chasing your tail.  `Date` is just a container for the number of milliseconds since the epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT).  It doesn't internally carry a representation of a time zone (AFAIK).

For example...

```
String epochTime = "1436831775043";
Date UTCDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(epochTime));
// Prints the "representation" of the Date
System.out.println(UTCDate);

// Local date/time format...
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
try {
    System.out.println("local format: " + simpleDateFormat.format(UTCDate));
    System.out.println("local Date: " + simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(UTCDate)));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication203.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

// UTC date/time format
try {
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println("utc format: " + simpleDateFormat.format(UTCDate));
    System.out.println("utc date: " + simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(UTCDate)));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication203.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Tue Jul 14 09:56:15 EST 2015
local format: 14/07/2015 9:56:15 AM
local Date: Tue Jul 14 09:56:15 EST 2015
utc format: 13/07/2015 11:56:15 PM
utc date: Tue Jul 14 09:56:15 EST 2015
```

If you have a look at `local Date` and `utc date` they are the same thing, even though the `local format` and `utc format` are formatted correctly.

So, instead of chasing your tale trying to get `Date` to "represent" a value you want, either use Java 8's Time API or JodaTime to manage the Time Zone information or simply format the `Date` into the Time Zone you want...

Further, if we do something like...

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
Date localDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(UTCDate));
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date utcDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(UTCDate));

System.out.println(localDate.getTime());
System.out.println(utcDate.getTime());

System.out.println(localDate.equals(utcDate));
```

It will print...

```
1436831775000
1436831775000
true
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful extra information. But the other answer was simpler. :)

Comment: All comes down to what you're trying to achieve, the point is you can only effect the format of `Date` object ;)

Comment: Small tip: java.time has a constant for the UTC zone, on a subclass of `ZoneId`, `ZoneOffset`. So, instead of `ZoneId.of("UTC")` use `ZoneOffset.UTC`.